# Est-ce que « j’aime lire » et « j’aime à lire » sont des phrases synonymes ?

Tags: prépositions

Je me suis aperçu que le verbe *aimer* peut être suivi par *à + infinitif*. Alors, est-ce que le sens change aussi quand on ajoute la préposition *à* ? Ou, est-ce juste un langage plus soutenu ?

> J’aime lire. ⟷ J’aime à lire.

---

Est-ce qu’un phénomène similaire existe pour les autres verbes d’appréciation, comme ci-dessous ?

> J’adore lire. ⟷ J’adore à lire.
>
> Je déteste lire. ⟷ Je déteste à lire.

Comment: http://www.tour-europe-velo.eu/article-du-journal-local/ Là, on a écrit : *« ils aiment à partager ... »*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Aimer à* + *verbe à l'infinitif* est une construction plutôt rare. *aimer* rajoute au verbe la notion d'une action souvent répétée et en général par plaisir.
"ils aiment à partager leur devise préférée" pourrait être compris comme "on peut souvent les entendre déclamer leur devise".

Answer (score -2):

Même après réflexion, je ne pense pas qu'il est possible d'utiliser le verbe "aimer" suivi de la préposition "à". En tout cas, "j'aime à lire" est incorrect.

Même remarque pour "adorer" ou "détester", ces verbes s'emploient sans la préposition "à".

Où avez-vous lu qu'il est possible d'écrire "aimer + à" ?

Comment: Voice la phrase exacte que j’ai lue : *ils aiment à partager leur devise préférée : « un voyageur revient avec un préjugé de moins et une idée de plus. »* Source : http://www.tour-europe-velo.eu/article-du-journal-local/

Comment: This is found in literary style. One example comes to mind with the π rhyme: *Que j'aime à faire apprendre un nombre utile aux sages...* => 3.1415926535...

Comment: @GAMPUB - It's probably not the best example, because there was a need for an "accceptable" one letter word in the mnemonic expression. Another known example is "J'aime à vous voir frémir à ce funeste nom" (Jean RACINE, Phèdre. I, 3), but the "à" contributes to the number of syllables of the alexandrine.

Comment: My point was, and is, that this construction belongs with literary expression. By the way, classic versification as used by Racine imposes the same kind of constraints on syllables as he mentioned rhyme...

Comment: @GAMPUB - You are right: using "j'aime à ..." indicates a literary intent, e.g. in a quote from Stendhal on travel: «Ce que j'aime à voir dans une ville, ce sont ses habitants.»

Comment: Merci @Geert pour ces précisions. Effectivement, cette formule "aimer à" existe bien, mais tellement rare. Et son utilisation la plus connue est le fameux "aimer à la folie".